# Graph API for group's jobs?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-group

I am able to fetch all my group's feed just fine, but there are "jobs" being posted using the "Create Job" button (https://www.facebook.com/jobs_composer/group..), that are not included in the {id}/feed API.

Is there a special endpoint for that?

Comment: Not sure whether those are available via API at all. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/jobs-xml/getting-started#reference has a link to a “Jobs Feed”, but that link is broken, and this part of the documentation applies to pages, not groups, to begin with.

Comment: @CBroe oh no! Is there a way to confirm by asking Facebook support somehow?

Comment: Facebook Developers Group on Facebook, or via their bug tracker.